# How to set default value of parameter to Null in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Can anyone tell me how to set default value of parameter to Null.

I tried this.

```
=Parameters!rp_GIIN.Value="",nothing,Parameters!rp_GIIN.Value)
```

Comment: what is the datatype of `Parameters!rp_GIIN.Value` ?

Comment: @pedram: datatype is varchar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set Default value to Null like this way, just go to the report parameter ,right click on it and go to Parameter Properties and select Default values tab and set `(Null)`

[image]

Expression could be,

```
=IIF(Parameters!rp_GIIN.Value="",Nothing,Parameters!rp_GIIN.Value)
```

Comment: it shows an error, In SSRS we have to use nothing instead of Null.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issues. Finally I find the cause is that the `Available Values` don't contain the `default value` I want to set, it is the `(Null)`. So after I add `UNION SELECT NULL` into the `Available Values` Dataset, it works.